# Moving average by day of the week by level

Tags: r, forecasting

Quick R question: I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
Outlet        weekday    visitors   Month
jackInthebox    Monday  10          July      
jackInthebox    Monday  11          July       
jackInthebox    Tues    15          July
jackInthebox    Tues    16          July 
jackInthebox    Wed     30          July
jackInthebox    Wed     28          July 
KFC             Monday  50          July 
KFC             Monday  53          July 
KFC             Tues    60          July 
KFC             Tues    64          July
KFC             Wed     30          July
KFC             Wed     31          July
```

I want to do a moving average forecast but grouping by day of the week and by outlets first. So get a forecast for jackinthebox for the next 5 Mondays, and the next 5 Tuesdays and so on and so for forth. and this is for each outlet. And hopefully add an outlet label and day of the week label so I know which belongs to which.

right now I'm attempting to do it in a for loop but running into issues with the grouping portion of it.

Again, the goal is to do a rolling average forecast but based on the day of the week and the month ( forgot to include that in there. There are multiple outlets and months) for each outlet

Any assistance will be great!!

Comment: what is your expected output for the sample data?

Answer (score 0):

`roll` calculates the rolling mean of 5 or fewer if there are not 5.  `ave` applies it to each group.

```
library(zoo)

roll <- function(x) rollapplyr(x, 5, mean, partial = TRUE)
transform(DF, ma = ave(visitors, Outlet, weekday, Month, FUN = roll))
```

The result adds the ma column to the input:

```
         Outlet weekday visitors Month   ma
1  jackInthebox  Monday       10  July 10.0
2  jackInthebox  Monday       11  July 10.5
3  jackInthebox    Tues       15  July 15.0
4  jackInthebox    Tues       16  July 15.5
5  jackInthebox     Wed       30  July 30.0
6  jackInthebox     Wed       28  July 29.0
7           KFC  Monday       50  July 50.0
8           KFC  Monday       53  July 51.5
9           KFC    Tues       60  July 60.0
10          KFC    Tues       64  July 62.0
11          KFC     Wed       30  July 30.0
12          KFC     Wed       31  July 30.5
```

**Note:** This is the assumed input `DF`:

```
Lines <- "
Outlet        weekday    visitors   Month
jackInthebox    Monday  10          July      
jackInthebox    Monday  11          July       
jackInthebox    Tues    15          July
jackInthebox    Tues    16          July 
jackInthebox    Wed     30          July
jackInthebox    Wed     28          July 
KFC             Monday  50          July 
KFC             Monday  53          July 
KFC             Tues    60          July 
KFC             Tues    64          July
KFC             Wed     30          July
KFC             Wed     31          July"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: I'm getting this error message. Do by any chance know what might be the cause.  Error in seq.default(start.at, NROW(data), by = by) : 
  wrong sign in 'by' argument

Comment: Start a new R session.  Copy and paste the code in the Note at the end of the answer and then copy and paste the code in the body of the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow but will do.